# Error in loading items in Alfresco YUI datatable

Tags: json, datatable, yui, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am using alfresco 5.0.d version needs to populate the custom model properties in YUI datatable and in response I am getting the JSON as below.

```
{
    "agency" : [
    {
        "agencyname": "1212",
        "agencycode": "1212",
        "createDate": "23/03/2016"
    }]
}
```

custom-users-min.js file: Generating the request and populating the resultlist.

```
config : {
    responseType : YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON,
    responseSchema : {
        resultList:"agency"
    }
    }
}
```

customagency.get.json.ftl file:

```
<#import "customagency.lib.ftl" as customagencyLib/>
<@customagencyLib.agencyJSON agency=agency/>
```

I am getting the message as Error loading items inside the alfresco YUI datatable. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying the parseJson before populating the data in YUI datatable.Resolved